# Appium Setup - Determining what jdk version I am using on mac

Tags: java, macos

I am following a guide to set up Appium on my mac. It is asking me to set my JAVA_Home variables. They are using: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/**jdk1.8.0_192.jdk**/Contents/Home

They have instructed me to replace **jdk1.8.0_192.jdk** with my own version of JDK.
How would I find out what my JDK is?
I have tried using: java -version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS

I am unsure how to translate that into the correct JDK.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I not super familiar with Mac but can you run "whereis java" from your shell and give me the output?

Answer (score 0):

For the currently used jdk version;

**/usr/libexec/java_home -V**

You can use this command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the jdk version using the below command:
ls  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).